# Do cursed chests from the "Damned" aspect replace normal chests that would have spawned?

Tags: dead-cells

The description for the "Damned" aspect says "Cursed chests spawn rate is doubled". Do the extra cursed chests replace normal non-cursed chests that would have spawned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently no.

> For biomes with a 100% chance of spawning a cursed chest, excluding Prison Depths and Corrupted Prison, there will now always be an **additional** cursed chest.
> For any other biome, it will take the percentage chance, double it and roll that chance twice. This means that it's possible to get an **additional** 2 cursed chests.

You can see that cursed chests have a [fixed chance of spawning](https://deadcells.fandom.com/wiki/Objects#Chances_of_spawning), depending on the biome.

Source, [Dead Cells wiki](https://deadcells.fandom.com/wiki/Aspects).